# nuget fails on RHEL7.9 OpenShift container

Tags: nuget, containers, openshift, rhel

I'm working on OpenShift container, need to push some `.nupkg` package based on`.nuspec` file. I can't even run help, nor `nuget pack` or `push`, when trying to execute `nuget` in cli is giving me error.

```
sh-4.2$ nuget 
Access to the path '/.config/NuGet' is denied.
```

If I would like to pack it, error is the same :

```
sh-4.2$ nuget pack RDependencies.nuspec 
Access to the path '/.config/NuGet' is denied.
```

It was installed while Building container, with
`RUN yum install -y nuget; yum clean all`

Container is based on: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)

And nuget bin:

```
sh-4.2$ whereis nuget
nuget: /usr/bin/nuget
sh-4.2$ cat /usr/bin/nuget
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/mono/nuget/NuGet.exe "$@"

sh-4.2$
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to force nuget to create/read from /tmp/ directory which I've got access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I have figure it. The main problem here is OpenShift temporary user which is created during deployment. It doesn't have home directory created, and HOME env variable is set in root dir : `HOME=/`

After changing it to, e.g. /tmp/

```
export HOME=/tmp/home_dir/
```

It starts to work

```
sh-4.2$ nuget
NuGet Version: 2.8.7.0
usage: NuGet <command> [args] [options] 
Type 'NuGet help <command>' for help on a specific command.

sh-4.2$ nuget pack
Please specify a nuspec or project file to use.
sh-4.2$
```